# Converting a Transform to a Matrix4f

Tags: c++, eigen

This is very likely a simple thing, but I am stuck. I have an `Eigen::transform`:

```
Eigen::Transform<float, 3, Eigen::Affine>
```

I need to convert this to a `Matrix4f`:

`const Eigen::Matrix4f T`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the matrix by calling the `matrix()` method:

```
Eigen::Transform<float, 3, Eigen::Affine> tr;
const Eigen::Matrix4f mat = tr.matrix();
```

Comment: Perfect.Thank you very much.